# railsを再起動する時に500エラーを出さないようにしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

rails + unicorn + nginx
の環境でサイトを運営しています。

サイトに変更を加えた時、railsとunicornを再起動するのですが、終了してから起動するまでの間にアクセスするとnginxから500がかえってしまいます(当然ですが)。

このダウンタイムをなくするにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

ちなみに今は以下のコマンドを実行して再起動しています。

```
kill -9 `cat /tmp/unicorn.pid`
bundle exec unicorn -D -c /rails/config/unicorn_production.rb -E production
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[biola/turnout](https://github.com/biola/turnout) を使うと、簡単にメンテナンス中の画面を表示することができます。

Gemfile

```
gem 'turnout'
```

bundle install

```
$ bundle intall
```

メンテナンスモードスタート

```
$ rake maintenance:start
```

メンテナンスモード終了

```
$ rake maintenance:end
```

参考サイト
http://morizyun.github.io/blog/turnout-maintenance-rails/
※ Capistranoと連携してデプロイ処理の一環としてメンテ画面を出すことも可能です。

Answer (score 2):

SIGKILL（-9）ではなくUSR2シグナルを送れば良いです。

```
kill -USR2 masterのPID
```

そうすれば、旧プロセスを残しつつ新しいプロセスを起動できます。

- http://tachesimazzoca.github.io/wiki/rails3/unicorn.html
- http://techracho.bpsinc.jp/piichan1031/2010_07_09/2075